# Google Map web service in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to wrap google map  API v3(javascript) to wrap in a .net web service? I want users to call functions exposed from this web service to show map on the web pages. this web service will be running on remote web server. Several (lets say 20) websites can use same service to display/interect maps. Web service will be helpful if we wish to add any functionality/feature in websites. We will have to change code at only one place(service) and new features will be reflected on each website consuming the service.

Comment: This probably violates all sorts of license agreements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I checked you can only use Google Maps directly within a browser (through their Java script API) . I think that to do what you want would require you direct access to their map tiles, which, to my knowledge is not permitted.

If you really need to use Google Maps and Web services, what you could do would be to let the Web service provide you with a set of points, you could use some sort of labelling to identify between points, hence apply different markers (this should allow you to make your application more maintainable). These points, which will be in the form of GPS co-ordinates will then be rendered directly by Google Maps through Google's v3 GoogleMaps API.

Comment: Is there some other way to avoid java script programming/code to write in web site application.

Comment: @Himanshu There could be a way, but that most likely excludes Google Maps.

Comment: Okay, its fine. Please tell, is it possible in WCF service to return .aspx page for some request?

Comment: @Himanshu: I am not that fluent in ASP.NET, but I would assume that from the code behind, you would be able to write out the .aspx code your webservice would generate.